# modify dictionary during iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looping through a `sorteddict`. Sometimes during the loop, I need to reinsert the same object with a different "key" (always greater, so always appearing later in the loop) and still get this object during the loop.

The reason for this : the dict is storing objects using a "cost" as the key. I'm trying to select the n objects minimizing the total cost. But the cost of an object can increase depending on previously selected objects.

Usually, the advice for people trying to modify a dict during iteration is to use a copy. But here I don't see how this would apply, I don't want to modify the dictionary, I'm trying to get the order of objects.

I tried something like this :

```
from blist import sorteddict

d = sorteddict({ 0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 5:'D'})
selection = []

for cost in d:
    # If 'A' is in selection, the cost of 'B' becomes 4
    new_cost = 4 if 'A' in selection and d[cost]=='B' else cost

    if new_cost == cost:
        selection.append(d[cost])
    else:
        d[new_cost] = d[cost]

    print(d[cost])
```

(I simplified the relationship between objects cost in this very simple example with 'A' and 'B')
I was trying to get :

```
A
B
C
B
D
```

And : `selection = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D']`. But I got a runtime error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-130-a45532380c1c>", line 1, in <module>
    for k in d:

  File "/local1/public/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/blist/_sortedlist.py", line 427, in __iter__
    raise RuntimeError('Set changed size during iteration')

RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

Is there some kind of data structure that would allow this (or a better way to solve this problem) ?

Comment: Well you are trying to modify the dictionary, that's exactly what `d[new_cost] = d[cost]` does.

Comment: That is true, but that was not really my objective here. In the code following this I use `selection`, not the dict. (the dict is no longer used after the loop)

Comment: It's usually much, much easier not to mutate the data you're iterating over and just make a copy with relevant changes. It's also significantly less error-prone. Unless you operate on gigabytes of data, it shouldn't have a performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add keys to a dict you are iterating over, that is changing the size of the dict, you can use `.keys` to avoid the error without making a full copy of the dict:

```
for cost in list(d.keys()):
```

Comment: I get the same error replacing `for cost in d:` by `for cost in d.keys():`

Comment: You need to call list on the keys, I edited for python3

Comment: That gives me `A B C D`. I am trying to get `A C B D` (but maybe this is not doable with dictionary)

Comment: @Nihl, if you are relying on being able to use the updated values in the dict as you iterate, that is not going to work as you cannot modify the dict adding keys while iterating. What in simplified terms do you want to achieve? If you look at the dict at the end then `sorteddict({0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 4: 'B', 5: 'D'})` is in the order you seem to want the keys

Comment: I precisely want to update value in the iteration. During the iteration, the cost of an object can increase and change because of what is already in `selection`. I want to get it in the correct order. Here, the order should be  `selection=[A,C,B,D]`, because once I add `A` to selection, `B` has cost higher than `C` but still lower than `B`. I found a way to do it in the end, see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it using `sortedlist` to store the keys (`sorteddict` and `sortedset` can't be edited in a loop, but `sortedlist` can, not sure why).

```
In [5]: from blist import sorteddict, sortedlist
   ...: 
   ...: d = sorteddict({ 0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 5:'D'})
   ...: keys = sortedlist(d.keys())
   ...: selection = []
   ...: 
   ...: for cost in keys:
   ...:     # If 'A' is in selection, the cost of 'B' becomes 4
   ...:     new_cost = 4 if 'A' in selection and d[cost]=='B' else cost
   ...:     
   ...:     if new_cost == cost:
   ...:         selection.append(d[cost])
   ...:     else:
   ...:         d[new_cost] = d[cost]
   ...:         keys.add(new_cost)
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: print('selection =',selection)

selection = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D']
```

I suppose now, a simple `dict` could be used instead of `sorteddict`. Still a bit of a tweak, so I'll leave the question opened in case someone find a more satisfying answer.